# How to NOT attach pergola close to house

Tags: pergola

I want to build a pergola over my back patio slab.  I want it to be "immediately" when you walk out the back door.

With that being said, for simplicity sake I'd rather ***not* attach the pergola to the house** and have to deal with a solid mount from the pergola to the house.

Is this ok/normal?

If it is, **what kind of spacing should I put between the pergola and the house** to not run into any issues.  I can't imagine a pergola would sway too much, but I am close to the coast and we can have windy days of course.

So, for example, if the pergola is 4 inches off of the house is that safe?  Anything else I need to consider here to have a pergola *close* to the house (close as possible) but not attached to the house?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it that you want to avoid adding any fixing to the house (such as small brackets to tie them together) completely, or that you want to avoid using the house as a structural part of your pergola?

Comment: @Dan Yes, completely.  I want zero attachments between the house and the pergola, but I want the pergola to be as close to the house as possible.  Thanks!